# Autoscroll reset to form endless vertical loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm looking to reset my vertical scroller. Basically once it reaches the end I haven't been able to transition it through again. An endless loop if you will.

Below is my script

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var div = jQuery('.scroll');
setInterval(function(){
    var pos = div.scrollTop();
    div.scrollTop(pos + 2);
}, 200)
});
```

What I was thinking was resetting like below, but that didn't work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var div = jQuery('.scroll');
setInterval(function(){
    var pos = div.scrollTop();
    div.scrollTop(pos + 2);
}, 200)
scrollTop =0;
});
```

HTML Structure

```
<div class="scroll">
  test 
   <br><br>   test 0
   <br><br>   test 1
   <br><br>   test 2
   <br><br>   test 3
   <br><br>  test 4
 </div>
```

Comment: can you add a demo ??

Comment: @Mritunjay I'm adding the html structure now. Test 4 is where it no longer scrolls. It pauses there and I'm looking to get "test" to begin once we get to that point.

Comment: Are you particulary referring to scrollTop = 0 after the setInterval function.? If so, it won't work. Because, the setInterval function repeats after the specified interval. But the scrollTop = 0 executes only once and that too before the first execution of the interval callback.

Comment: @elf Right, I'm trying to loop the vertical scroll so that it creates a constant loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this, get the scroll top and scrollHeight if scroll top greater than scrollHeight reset it to 0

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  var div = jQuery('#scroll');
  setInterval(function(){
    var pos = div.scrollTop();
    var scrollHeight = div.prop("scrollHeight") - div.height();
    if(pos < scrollHeight)
    {
       div.scrollTop(pos + 2);
    }
    else
    {
       div.scrollTop(0);
    }
  }, 200)
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also pauses at the bottom.

Comment: can you just check whether you are getting the scrollHeight or not

Comment: just console.log(scrollHeight)  with in the interval function

Comment: Just added `$('.listprice').html(scrollHeight);` below the scrollHeight var and I'm getting nothing in my `<p class="listprice"></p>`

Comment: My mistake. I was using $ as opposed to jQuery. Yes it looks like it's getting a reading of 860.

Comment: just use console.log(scrollHeight)

Comment: you are getting the correct scrollHeight it should work

Comment: To add to this. I also outputted the pos and that pauses at 812. Then doesn't do anything else. So we have a height of 860px and it scrolls only to 812 before it pauses.

Comment: use the edited answer we have to subtract the div height from the scrollHeight